Hardware device protecting phone from falling and breaking when USB cable is pulled
The other day I found myself home with a hungry stomach and a hurried mindframe and urgently needed to charge my phone so that I could have available my schedule and my contacts so that I may be able to call them in case of an emergency or if I found myself at loss.
My daughter's phone was charging, and as I happened to give out, later, the phone had charged all morning (while my daughter was at school), and was thus fully charged.
As my daughter does not like me touching her phone, I didn't grab it (as I was not in the habit of doing so).
So in my bodily state, I just pulled on the USB cable to charge my phone.
Alas, the pull, despite it's rough suddenness which couldn't be too hard because otherwise the cable would break, did not make it, the phone came along with the cable pull and the friction on the surface where the phone was resting was not enough, ... and the phone fell off the surface (as I pulled onto the cable).
The cable, was thus, disconnected. But the phone screen was broken despite the phone cover, which, not extruding much, provided for a poor phone screen protection.
I had to explain the situation and apologize for what had happened.
But, I don't want this to happen again.
So, I am wondering, is there any phone clamp (as in the below drawing, that I can purchase online or in stores, so that the phone will not break when I pull the cable from the charge)?

In this picture the yellow cable with green connector is a USB cable. The black part represents the smatphone. And the blue part is the "clamp", or rather, perhaps it would be better named a "bracket", within which the phone is placed on one side and the cable attached from the other side of the bracket hole. The bracket holds the phone like a hand while flat on the table, preventing it from being pulled out of the table. I have drawn in red some stickers which are used to attach the clamp/bracket to the table permanently.
Are such devices available?
Where can I get such a device?
Thanks.

Can't you just 3D print it?

Unfortunately pulling the cable (versus the connector) is generally considered bad practice, as it leads to additional strain on the cable and connector. What about just getting a second dedicated charger for yourself?

Removing the cable from a device by giving it a sudden yank, as you would if you were pulling a dinner cloth out from under a table full of crockery, is the issue here. Broken crockery, or in this case a phone, is a possibility of doing something that inherently entails such risks.
If a phone clamp device such as the one you've described exists, it doesn't change the fact that removing the cable in that manner is not the right way to do it. Not only does it risk pulling the device along with it, you're also risking damaging the cable and the port on the device itself.
Safely removing the cable takes no more effort and won't cost a penny more.
Having said that though, whilst it sounds like you did something that wasn't particular smart, as we all do from time to time. It does also sound like your motivation of wanting to respect your daughter's wishes for you to not touch her phone, may mean that she has something to learn from the incident too. If even holding her phone in place in order to remove the charging cable isn't acceptable to her, then perhaps she should charge her phone elsewhere.

Yeah, but you're cheaper and easier just gluing a car mobile phone holder to a phone charger, instead.
